# Configuring Netflix Eureka with Spring Boot Microservices on AWS EC2 (Route 53 + VPC)

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, netflix-eureka, amazon-vpc

We are trying to deploy a set microservices (written in Spring Boot 2) to AWS and we want to enable service discovery using Eureka.

The Eureka server is running on Tomcat 9 on a Linux EC2 instance. The Eureka dashboard is reachable, but clients will not register. Clients register successfully on localhost, however.

Due to resource constraints, we are unable to use EIPs for the microservices. We are using Route 53 in conjunction with a Virtual Private Cloud for routing.

I found some mentions of this setup being mostly compatible, but no instructions:

[Register VPC Eureka node in Route53 instead of EIP](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/23#event-57726882)

[Service Discovery - Microservices on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/microservices-on-aws/service-discovery.html)

Here are our Eureka server properties:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

# below are prod environment variables
eureka.us-east-1.availabilityZones=us-east-1a
eureka.serviceUrl.us-east-1a=https://eureka.mydomain.com/

eureka.shouldUseDns=true
eureka.eurekaServer.domainName=eureka.mydomain.com/
eureka.eurekaServer.port=8081
eureka.eurekaServer.context=svc
eureka.datacenter=cloud
```

Here are our Eureka client properties:

```
eureka.us-east-1.availabilityZones=us-east-1a
eureka.serviceUrl.us-east-1a=https://eureka.mydomain.com/

eureka.shouldUseDns=true
eureka.eurekaServer.domainName=eureka.mydomain.com/
eureka.eurekaServer.port=8081
eureka.eurekaServer.context=svc
eureka.datacenter=cloud
```

Any help with our situation would be very much appreciated! Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you are running Eureka on the port 8081. Eureka server usually runs on port 8761.
2. Have you created Route 53 endpoints (TXT Records) Ref: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Deploying-Eureka-Servers-in-EC2
3. Eureka Clients need to have below configuration:
   https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html

`

```
   @Bean
   @Autowired
   @Profile("!default")
   public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
    AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
    config.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicHostname));
    config.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicIpv4));
    config.setNonSecurePort(appPort);
    config.setDataCenterInfo(info);
    return config;
   }
```

`

Hope this helps.